# canvas is loading correctly on page reload only

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

i have created a ripple effect in canvas ,
 for that i have used four circles which are drawn one by one after some interval and their radius is increased in every loop ,
 like first wave then second wave then third and in last fourth wave.

**but the problem is its not being loaded as it should be for the first time , until i refresh/reload my page it appears as i require**

**screenshots are attached**

here is my code

```
 <canvas id="myCanvas" ></canvas>


var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 var ww =   window.innerWidth; 
 var wh = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = ww * 0.98;
canvas.height = wh * 0.98;
var CW = canvas.width;
var CH = canvas.height;


var radiusFirstWave = 20
var radiusSecondWave = 20
var radiusThirdWave = 20
var radiusFourthWave = 20

function FirstWave() {
//opacity = 1;

   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, CW, CH);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0,0, radiusFirstWave, 0, 2 * Math.PI);


     ctx.lineWidth = 2;

       ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(00,00,ff)" ;

    ctx.stroke();

    radiusFirstWave += (CW*speed)/3000;

    if (radiusFirstWave >(ww*FinalRadius)/100)
    {radiusFirstWave =  InitialRadius*ww/100;}


    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        FirstWave();
    });
} 



FirstWave();    

 setTimeout(function SecondWave() {
// some code

    rAF = requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        SecondWave();
    });
    },  500);

 setTimeout(function ThirdWave() {
 //some code
    rAF = requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        ThirdWave();
    });
    }, 1000);

 setTimeout(function FourthWave() {
 //some code 

    rAF = requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        FourthWave();
    });
    }, 1500);
```

here is the output when i open it in browser for the first time ,instead of appearing after `500 millisecond`   they are being loaded once 
[image]

But when i refresh the page it shows like this, this is what exactly i coded it for 
[image]

a gap between circles is clearly visible

what  are your suggestions ?
is it like canvas is not being load completely when i draw these circles for the first time in browser ?
and second time after reloading the page it is being fetched from the cache ?
any kind of help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you reduce your code to a minimally verifiable example? Preferably also pasting the entire HTML file (reduced to a minimum that can be reproduced). You may be using the `canvas` element before it is ready. Try to open the page in Firefox and use Developer Console to see any errors the browser is giving you.

Comment: @amn  i have reduced my code also there is no error in developer console.

Answer (score 0):

Do not run multiple requestAnimationFrame loops concurrently like that.

Your calls will get stacked until just before the next screen refresh, so that may work, and will not have too much performance overhead... **but** in your implementation you cannot be sure of the order they have been stacked, because you call them from randomly firing setTimeout.

I mean randomly, because with regard to screen-refresh sequence, and requestAnimationFrame callbacks calls, **it is random**. The next call of the already running loops will get stacked only just before the next screen-refresh. Your timeout have great chances to fall before => it will get stacked first.

So you may very well end up calling [*FourthWave*, *ThirdWave*, *SecondWave*, *FirstWave*] in this order, and the three first calls would all have been cleared by the `clearRect` in *FirstWave*.

So instead of running those 4 animation loops, the easiest way is to make use of flags, and a single animation loop:

```
var flags = [1,0,0,0];
function anim() {
  if(flags[0]) FirstWave();
  if(flags[1]) SecondWave();
  if(flags[2]) ThirdWave();
  if(flags[3]) FourthWave();
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}
setTimeout(function() {
  flags[1] = 1;
}, 500);
...
```

Comment: what `flags[1] = 1 ` does ? means how will it invoke `anim() `

Comment: It raises our flag, so that at the next iteration of `anim`, it will call `SecondWave` (`if(flags[1])` will be truthy.)

Comment: its behaving the same as my previous output